# CTest: How to skip other tests if the "precheck" test fails?

Tags: cmake, ctest

I'm adding tests to my project and all the tests have some prerequisites so I add a *precheck* test which all other tests depend on. If the *precheck* fails then I'd like the other tests to stop immediately.

```
add_test(
    NAME precheck
    COMMAND false
)

add_test(
    NAME test-1
    COMMAND true
)
add_test(
    NAME test-2
    COMMAND true
)
set_tests_properties(
    test-1 test-2
    PROPERTIES
    DEPENDS precheck
)
```

But seems like the `DEPENDS` property only impact the order of tests:

```
$ make test
Running tests...
Test project /root/ibvq/frkcrpg/b
    Start 1: precheck
1/3 Test #1: precheck .........................***Failed    0.00 sec
    Start 2: test-1
2/3 Test #2: test-1 ...........................   Passed    0.00 sec
    Start 3: test-2
3/3 Test #3: test-2 ...........................   Passed    0.00 sec

67% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 3

Total Test time (real) =   0.02 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - precheck (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 8
```

So how can I make the failed *precheck* stop other tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using CMake version 3.7 or later, you can use the [test fixture](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/FIXTURES_REQUIRED.html) related properties.

For earlier versions of CMake, have your `precheck` test create a dummy file on success that your other tests depend on by setting the [REQUIRED_FILES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/REQUIRED_FILES.html) property.